# Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name returns asp.net server credential not the users credetials

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building a simple intranet site and want to get the employees user name, but when i use Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name , i keep getting the servers credentials and not the users. what am i doing wrong and is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the authentication mode to "Windows":

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Then, in your code, use `Me.User.Identity.Name` to get the user's login id.

Note that this is an ASP.NET 2.0 for Visual Studio 2005 example. It may have changed if you are using something older or newer.

**ASIDE EDIT:** Why does the main page show this topic as being posted 51 minutes ago, but I just now see it's from Feb!?!?!?