# Users Indistinguishable in Hosted ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am working on a hosted ASP.Net application, with Windows Authentication, and I need to get the username for various personalisation tasks. The directory on the host machine is set to have Windows Authentication and the `web.config` file also has:-

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

in it. I have tried various methods within the application to get the user name with the following results:-

```
Source                                                         Result
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  'EZ\urlname_a'
System.Environment.UserName                                    'NETWORK SERVICE'
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name              ''
this.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]                     ''
this.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]                      ''
this.User.Identity.Name                                        ''
```

thanks to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249887/reading-windows-credentials), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280402/get-client-user-name-from-a-web-application-running-in-a-web-server-with-windows), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000100/request-logonuseridentity-name-returns-asp-net-server-credential-not-the-users-c), among others. None of these distinguish between the various usernames that were entered.

Is there anything else I can try in code to get the name (or some proxy for the name)? Is there anything I can check for in `web.config`? Or if I need to take the matter up with the host, is there any intelligent question I can ask?

**Edit** I have set the application directory and .Net version using the host's IIS Dialogue.

Comment: Are you hosting using IIS?

Comment: @Amber, yes, I believe so.

Comment: You should check that you only have Windows authentication enabled in the IIS Manager then. As it currently uses 'NETWORK SERVICE' which is (presumably) the application pool setting.

Comment: Any updates here?  I'm having similar issues and I've already checked that Windows Authentication is the only option set to true.

Comment: @beaudetious, Sorry to say there aren't. The customer backed out so I've not touched it since.

Comment: No such luck for me. ;)  I'm starting over in the sense that I'll move my angular app code to a new ASP.Net MVC/Web API project.  It seems to be something with former project structure/references.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set IIS to use Windows Authentication only, then use Page.User.Identity.Name or similar to fetch the windows user name.

From the Authentication pane, set the Windows Authentication to Enabled and Disable anonymous authentication.